# Javascript, issue with Connect style.display and style.transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, display

I have a little problem with div swap. I want to add a little animation to transition from div a to div b, but as you can see it doesn't work very well. 
I'm learning vanilla javascript and i don't want to use jQuery.

Could you explain me what i'm doing bad?

```js
function onHover(id1,id2){
  let div = document.getElementById(id1);
  let div2 = document.getElementById(id2);

  div.style.transition = "background 0.5s ease-in";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 

  if(div.style.display == "block"){
    div.style.display = "none"; 
    div2.style.display = "block";
  }else{
      div.style.display = "block";
      div2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#a {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

.bb {
  display:none;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" onmouseover="onHover('a','b')" >aaaa</div>
<span id="b" class="bb" onmouseout="onHover('a','b')">bbb</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following approach.

```js
var divA = document.querySelector('#a');
var text1 = "this is the text one.";
var text2 = "this is the text two.";
divA.innerHTML = text1;

function swap(e) {
  var elem = e.target;
  elem.innerHTML =
    elem.innerHTML === text1 ? text2 : text1;
  if (elem.classList.contains('blue')) {
    elem.classList.remove('blue');
  } else {
    elem.classList.add('blue');
  }
};

divA.addEventListener('mouseover', swap);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="box"></div>
```